# How to make share button like Facebook's or Twitter's

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, twitter, share

Some sites like Facebook & Twitter make their own share button (i.e. [tweet button](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet) & [FB share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)) that could be used in any other site, I want to make my own to help people share links to my site.

I've made the page for the sharing window `/sharer`, which could be opened using this function:

```
function openPopup(url){
  var width = 790;
  var height = 570;
  var top = screen.height/2 - height/2;
  var left = screen.width/2 - width/2;
  var windowFeatures = "location=yes, height=" + height + ", width=" + width + ", left=" + left + ", top=" + top;
  var windowUrl = "https://example.com/sharer?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
  var win = window.open(windowUrl, "_blank", windowFeatures);
}
```

and of course I need to host a javascript file to hold my code like the previous function,

but question is, how could I prepare a code that could be used by any other site to show my button properly with its own CSS & Javascript, and not to be affected by the hosting page that contains it?

Comment: Facebook and twitter insert iframes

Answer (score 2):

Facebook and twitter both load the button in an `iframe`, which totally isolates the CSS and Javascript from the parent page. If that's what you are after, I'd recommend doing the same thing.

Comment: Eventually they are using iframes, but why they start with a javascript code like this https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading instead of just giving the users the iframe code?

Comment: Right underneath the snippet on that page, it explains it's purpose. It optimizes loading of the widget by ensuring it's only loaded once, loading it asynchronously, and queuing any function calls until it's ready. That last part alludes to some of the extra benefits of JS initialization.. Both twitter and facebook have APIs that add functionality to their widgets and such, which can be accessed via JS (and ajax) once they've been properly initialized.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The JS creates the iframe element and inserts it into the page.